# Getting "502 Bad Geteway" when trying to upload large file in Aws Lambda deployed flask application

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, flask-wtforms

I have created a post endpoint for my flask application that endpoint works well when i try to upload small file (less than 30KB) but when the file size increases(greater then 50KB) i am getting a 502 bad gateway error is there any workaround for this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you using nginx to deploy your application?